# When does an operator commute with another operator given by a series?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $B$ is a bounded operator on some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, given by a series of the form
$$
B = I + \sum^\infty_{k = 1} c_k(I - A)^k
$$
where $A$ is a given bounded operator on $\mathcal{H}$. If $C$ is another operator that commutes with $A$ then according to Reed and Simon I'd need the series above to be asbsolutely convergent in order to conclude that $C$ also commutes with $B$.

Why do I need the absolute convergence ?

Comment: You don't need absolute convergence. It is sufficient that the series converges in the norm.

Answer (score 6):

Since the composition of operators is continuous in the norm topology, for every $X \in B(\mathcal{H})$, the set

$$Z(X) = \{ Y \in B(\mathcal{H}) : XY - YX = 0\}$$

is closed. It is in fact a closed subalgebra of $B(\mathcal{H})$, as one readily verifies.

So if $A \in Z(C)$, then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the operator

$$B_n = I + \sum_{k=1}^n c_k(I-A)^k$$

also belongs to $Z(C)$. Since $Z(C)$ is closed, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \lVert B_n - B\rVert \to 0$ is sufficient for the conclusion $B \in Z(C)$.